# How do I call a method into the public static class to be used?

Tags: java, call

I am new coder taking a class over computer science. We are working with Java. The assignment was given through a pdf that I reuploaded as a photo here https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNEdm.png. Here is my code so far.

```
public class LineEditor {
  private String myLine;

  public void insert(String str, int index) {
    String newmyLine = myLine;
    newmyLine = " world!";
    String sub = myLine.substring(0, index);
    String sub2 = myLine.substring(index, myLine.length()-1);
    System.out.print(sub + str + sub2);
  }

  }
  public void delete(String str) {

  }

  public void deleteAll(String str) {

  }
  public static void main(String[] aghs){
    insert("Hello ", 0);
  }
}
```

When I run this, I get the error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method insert(java.lang.String, int) from the type LineEditor

How can I take the insert method and use it in the main method? If any of my terminology is off, go ahead and tell me as well.

Comment: Make `insert` static

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`main` is a static method. You need to create an instance of your class with `new` and then call `insert` on it.

Eg:

```
public static void main(String[] aghs){
  LineEditor le = new LineEditor();
  le.insert("Hello ", 0);
}
```

The other option you have it to make method static, but having classes with a bunch of static methods can be a sign of bad object-oriented design. Of course this depends on the problem at hand.